# Access Popup.isopen On MainPage FromA Different Class

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Hi im looking to control the .isopen value from a different class, i have spent hours looking into this, ive tried all sorts, except a viewmodel which i don't really know much about, but just seems abit excessive to change one value, would be greatful if someone could point me in the right direction. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything beyond the simplest app you probably should look into separating your data from the presentation. You don't necessarily need the complexity of full MVVM for small apps, but the general concept is almost always good.

That said, another option is to write your MainPage as a singleton and export a static function which provides the MainPage instance and can be called from other apps. The standard MSDN sample template does this with a public Curren field

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page 
{ 
    public static MainPage Current; 

    public MainPage() 
    { 
        this.InitializeComponent(); 
        SampleTitle.Text = FEATURE_NAME; 

        // This is a static public property that allows downstream pages to get a handle to the MainPage instance 
        // in order to call methods that are in this class. 
        Current = this; 
    } 

    // Rest of MainPage class
}
```

Other classes can access public methods and fields from the MainPage class through the Current field:

```
MainPage.Current.MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
```

For encapsulation you may want to wrap that in a function rather than directly exposing MyPopup

```
public void RequestWidgetData()
{
    WidgetPopup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using of viewmodel is the right decision. In viewmodel you will create a property IsOpen and then bind your view to it. I'd strongly recomend you to use MVVM pattern while desining app for WinRT. Simple implementation will be something like this:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   {
       var handler = PropertyChanged;
       if (handler != null)
           handler(this, args);
   }
}

public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isOpen;
    public bool IsOpen 
    {
        get { return _isOpen; }
        set 
        {
            _isOpen = value;
            OnProperyChanged("IsOpen");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice but as i said i have no idea about view models is there any examples in the form of what i'm looking for thanks.

Comment: this is basic implementation of ViewModel. Set it as DateContext of the page, then bind IsOpen property of the view to IsOpen property of ViewModel.